# A Banach space in between $L^{1}$ and $L^{2}$, does it make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $L^{p} (A, B)$ be a collection of functions $f:A \mapsto B$ satisfying
$$(\|f\|_{p})^{p} := \int_{A} |f(x)|^{p} dx <\infty.$$

Now we consider functions $f:[0,1]^{2} \mapsto [0,1]$. We say
$f\in L^{p,q}:= L^{p}([0,1], L^{q}([0,1], [0,1]))$ if $f$ satisfies

(1) For all $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x, \cdot) \in L^{q}([0,1], [0,1])$, i.e. $\|f(x, \cdot)\|_{q}^{q} = \int_{[0,1]} |f(x, y)|^{q}dy < \infty$.

(2) $(\|f\|_{p,q})^{p} := \int_{[0,1]} \|f(x, \cdot)\|_{q}^{p} dx < \infty.$

My questions are

(Q1) Is $L^{1,2}$ a Banach space satisfying $L^{2}([0,1]^{2}, [0,1]) 
\subset L^{1,2} \subset
L^{1}([0,1]^{2}, [0,1])$?

(Q2) If Yes for (Q1), 
is it commonly used in any standard textbook? If not, why?

Comment: Without reading your whole argument, this cant be true since $L^2(\mathbb R^2) \not\subset L^1(\mathbb R^2)$.

Comment: @LeBtz Thanks, I've changed all domains to a finite interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1) these inclusions would hold if you restrict everything to bounded sets $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ and $B\subset \mathbb R$.

Q2) such spaces are commonly used in the theory of partial differential equations. For time dependent problems one often has $L^p$ estimates in time and $L^q$ estimates in space.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.